# TCP listen socket error

Tags: c#, sockets

I have 2 program, client and server, client program send data with specific port (EX:1370) by *TCP* protocol.
I use following code to wait for a client in my server program.

```
IPAddress IP = (my IP Address);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IP, 1370);

listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                          SocketType.Stream, 
                          ProtocolType.Tcp);
listenSocket.Bind((EndPoint) ipep);
listenSocket.BeginReceive(clientData, 0, clientData.Length,
                          SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveClient), null);
```

I have an error in last line, socket can not receive data in TCP protocol.
this code is work in UDP protocol very fine.
can you help me?! (thanks)

Comment: "I have an error" is pretty vague - could you give more details?

Comment: Listening sockets are usually used for accepting connections, not receiving data.  The interaction for UDP isn't the same as for TCP.  You might want to take a look at something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: Jon, error is: "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

Comment: forsvarir: I don't use Listen method for listen, the BeginReceive method wait for data in a new thead.

Comment: I know that i can use TCPListener class to resolve problem, but i don't want to use this class. how i can do it without TCPListener class?!

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, TCP/IP protocol has the **connection establishment** phase. So the server must call `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` and the client must call `connect()`. After connection is established, the server `accept()` returns a **new client-server** socket. This socket allows the server to communicate with the client (i.e. serve the connection).

I would like to recommend you the following examples:

1. [Synchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3).
2. [Synchronous Client Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The code should be something like this

```
IPAddress IP = (my IP Address);
listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IP, 1370);
listenSocket.Bind((EndPoint) ipep);

listenSocket.Listen(4);
// Create the call back for any client connections...
listenSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback (OnClientConnect), null);
```

and once the client is connected

```
// This is the call back function, which will be invoked when a client is connected
 public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
 {
   try
   {
        Socket workerSocket = m_mainSocket.EndAccept (asyn);        
        workerSocket.BeginReceive();                    
        // Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
        // other clients who are attempting to connect
        m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback ( OnClientConnect ),null);
   }
   catch(ObjectDisposedException)
    {
    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {
    }

  }
```

Comment: thank you very much... this code is work very fine. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
           public void Listen()
            {
            string portStr = "5656";
            int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
            // Create the listening socket...
            m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,                            SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Bind to local IP Address...
            m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
            // Start listening...
             m_mainSocket.Listen(4);
             btn_start.Enabled = false;
             lbl_connect.Visible = true;
            // Create the call back for any client connections...
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
           }



             public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
             {
             m_workerSocket[m_clientCount] = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);
            // Let the worker Socket do the further processing for the 
            // just connected client
            WaitForData(m_workerSocket[m_clientCount]);
            // Now increment the client count
            ++m_clientCount;
            // Display this client connection as a status message on the GUI    


            // Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
            // other clients who are attempting to connect
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
```

//** Waiting for client data

```
            public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
            {
                try
                {
                   if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                   {
                       // Specify the call back function which is to be 
                      // invoked when there is any write activity by the 
                      // connected client
                      pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                   }
                    SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                    theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;
                   // Start receiving any data written by the connected client
                   // asynchronously
                    soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,                                                      theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                               SocketFlags.None,
                               pfnWorkerCallBack,
                               theSocPkt);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException se)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
                    }

               }
```